# How to input only part of the video file in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg in order to process videos.

```
ffmpeg -i C:\test.mp4 [rest of the command]
```

When I use above command it process whole video. How can I select a paticular part of the video and process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done by using `-ss` and `-t` options.

`-ss`  seeks for the start position

`-t` limits the duration

so the command is like this.

```
ffmpeg -ss 50 -t 10 -i C:\test.mp4 [rest of the command]
```

this processes 10 seconds of video, starting at 50 and going onto 60.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following options:

This will stop writing output after duration reached:

```
-t duration (output).
```

This will stop writing output at position reached:

```
-to position (output).
```

This will set input time offset in seconds

```
-itsoffset offset (input).
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I want to process only a part of the video. Ex: from x to y. Not from the beginning always.